# Match dynamic data with match method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to match the dynamic route with the help of the match method but it is not working.

```
["payment", "portal", "animation"].each do |arg|
    define_method("profile_#{arg}") do 
        self.path.match("/users/\d+/#{arg}")
    end
end
```

So, this code self.path.match("/users/\d+/#{arg}") doesn't work with interpolation.

Whereas If I do something like below then it works. So, is there any way to match the data dynamically

```
self.path.match('/users/\d+/payment')
self.path.match('/users/\d+/portal')
self.path.match('/users/\d+/animation')
```

Comment: you just need to escape the backslash with another backslash e.g. `"/users/12/payment".match?("/users/\\d+/#{arg}") #=> true` but as pointed out by Sundeep you can just interpolate in the Regex (which is what `match` is doing with your String anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The \d+ expression doesn't work properly with doublequotes and the string interpolation. Here a sample path for "portal" and 2x ways to match it. (Tested with 2.5.5)

```
path = "somedir/users/#{rand(0..999)}/portal"

["payment", "portal", "animation"].each do |arg|
    define_method("profile_#{arg}") do
        path.match("/users/"+(/\d+/).to_s+"/#{arg}")
        # or 
        path.match('users/\d+/'+arg)
    end
end

puts profile_payment
puts profile_portal
puts profile_animation
```

Answer (score 1):

You can interpolate within a regexp literal itself.

```rb
?> s = "payment"
=> "payment"
>> %r(/users/\d+/#{s})
=> /\/users\/\d+\/payment/
```